# Let $F\subset E_i$ where $i$ is in the countable index set. In what condition can we guarantee that $\cap E_i$ exist?

Tags: set-theory

Let $F\subset E_i$ where $i$ is in the countable index set. In what condition can we guarantee that $\cap E_i$ exist?

I feel that there should be some sets $E_i$ that the intersection doesn't exist. But the book that I'm reading on field theory take the existence as granted and this really bugs me. If this question is too easy can someone give me just some tips?

Comment: Apply axiom schema of comprehension to the set $E_1$ using the following one-place formula $P(x)$: "for each $i$, it holds that $x \in E_i$".

Comment: When you say "Doesn't exist", do you really mean "doesn't exist", or just "is empty"?

Comment: What do you mean by 'exist'? Being non-empty, or being well-defined based on set theoretical axioms?

Comment: What I'm thinking is that $lim_{n\to\infty}\cap_i^n E_i$ might not exist as in real analysis. In other words $\cap_i^n E_i$ might keep decreasing as $n$ increases

Comment: It seems that this is out of the scope of my knowledge involving some set theory

Comment: What is $F$ here? You're never mentioning it again.

Comment: It's just a non-empty set. I should've been able to write a bertter question if I have some knowledge on set theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $I$ be a nonempty index set.  For each $i \in I$, let $E_i$ be a set.

$$
\bigcap_{i \in I} E_i= \{x\;:\; (\forall i \in I)\; x \in E_i\}
$$

---

If you have to do it by an [axiom of separation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/axiom+of+separation), then do this:
Since $I \ne \varnothing$, there is $a \in I$.  Now write it
$$
\bigcap_{i \in I} E_i= \{x \in E_a\;:\; (\forall i \in I)\; x \in E_i\}
$$

---

You are right: if $I = \varnothing$.  Then (if you use the axioms of ZFC) the intersection $\bigcap_{i\in I}E_i$ indeed does not exist.